# how to use wikipedia-API like google does?

Tags: api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

when i search something on google on the right side of the page i saw wiki-page for this item.
example: i searched for adriana lima
[image]

i am devoloping a search engine and i want the exact same thing. Heres my question. i learned how to use wikipedia API. but i couldn't find how i get this section as google does.

I'm showing which section i looking for in this picture.but i don't know what is the nameof this section and how to se it via wiki-API

Answer (score 1):

They could do it either by parsing the factbox themselves, or by using the data mined from factboxes by  **[DBPedia](http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Adriana_Lima)**.

You have yet another option, that wasn't there when Google started showing these snippets: **[WikiData](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q151866)** has an excellent API for that kind of work. Not every fact from the factbox is there, yet, but it is filling up quickly.